# How can Google Photos back up Google Keep notes with images?

Tags: google-photos, google-keep

Google Keep has the feature to directly take a photo and create a note with that photo.

How can I add these taken photos to the automatic back-up procedure of Google Photos?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry!

Comment: If I get some time, I will do a good search for you.

Comment: Appreciated, thank Ted! Indeed I currently don't have the time to dig deeper into that issue.